# UIButton's image with states

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I have `UIButton` and set its background image with proper code.

```
`[button setImage:self.image forState:UIControlStateNormal]`
```

and it shows the correct image when the button is initialized but I want to make the image gone when the state is `UIControlStateSelected`.

I was able to change the image when it's selected but do not know which is the right function or value to be set to no image when selected.

Should I make the `image alpha` to be `0.0`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using photoshop, create new image with transparent background. Save it as nope.png file, drag it to  your project. then

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nope.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

**Another way** is you need to create new image category :

```
@interface UIImage (UIImageFrameColor)
+(UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color andSize:(CGSize)size;
@end

@implementation UIImage (UIImageFrameColor)
+(UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color andSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 0);

    [color set];
    UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    [path fill];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
@end
```

Then you need to make a image have same color of background color of button supper view

```
    UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:button.supperview.backgroundColor andSize:button.frame.size];
    [button setImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `[button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this and I guess when it's nil, it grabs the default one which is the one from StateNormal.

Answer (score 1):

Try [button setSeleted:YES];

if you want to create a button like check list button. This is a example code:

```
[button setImage:imageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:imageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
.....

-(void)btnButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    [sender setSelected:!sender.selected];
}
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: My question is not getting a different image when it is in StateSelected but to make the default image to be completely transparency or not there at all.

Answer (score 1):

Please check and try . This may be useful to you :

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```